# SSL_CTX_set_client_cert_cb with certificate chain

Tags: openssl

OpenSSL Doc says: The client_cert_cb() cannot return a complete certificate chain, it can only return one client certificate.

In my case I want to return / set the certificate chain, but have no idea how it is doable. Any example how to do would be appreciated???

Answer (score 1):

In the Man Page of OpenSSL [SSL_CTX_set_client_cert_cb](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_client_cert_cb.html) command, it says, as you said in the question, `client_cert_cb() cannot return a complete certificate chain` however it also states a workaround for the problem:

> **BUGS**
>
> The client_cert_cb() cannot return a complete certificate chain, it
>   can only return one client certificate. If the chain only has a length
>   of 2, the root CA certificate may be omitted according to the TLS
>   standard and thus a standard conforming answer can be sent to the
>   server. For a longer chain, the client must send the complete chain
>   (with the option to leave out the root CA certificate). This can only
>   be accomplished by either `adding the intermediate CA certificates into the trusted certificate store for the SSL_CTX object (resulting in having to add CA certificates that otherwise maybe would not be trusted), or by adding the chain certificates using the SSL_CTX_add_extra_chain_cert function`, which is only available for the
>   SSL_CTX object as a whole and that therefore probably can only apply
>   for one client certificate, making the concept of the callback
>   function (to allow the choice from several certificates) questionable.

Does this apply to your situation?

---

**EDIT**

You can add chain certificates using [SSL_CTX_add_extra_chain_cert](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_add_extra_chain_cert.html) function. Note that, as it is stated in the quote, you don't have to send your root CA certificate.

Comment: How can i add intermediate CA certificates into the trusted certificate store for SSL_CTX object? Where will be Root CA set?

Comment: @user3027786 I have updated my answer regarding your comment. It could be very helpful if you can present some ways that you tried and failed so that we can easily spot the error in your code.